# element.onload vs element.addEventListener("load",callbak,false)

Tags: javascript, javascript-events, onload-event

Can someone please explain what the difference is between the following two ways to specifying onload callback functions in javascript?

```
element.onload = callback
```

AND

```
element.addEventListener("load",callbak,false)
```