# Javascript: ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm trying to call a function with `onchange()` in an input form.

When I check the console in Chrome, the code below returns:

> ReferenceError: changingNow is not defined

In safari, it says:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable changingNow

Here's the code:

```
function changingNow() {
 first_name=document.getElementById(first_name);
 last_name=document.getElementById(last_name);
 username=document.getElementById(username);
 category=document.getElementById(category);
 if ((first_name!=="")&&(last_name!=="")&&(username!=="")&&(category!="empty")) {
   form1.process.disabled = false;
 }
 else {
  form1.process.disabled = true;
 }

 document.getElementById('tweet').value = 'I just voted for '+first_name+' '+last_name+'('+username+')'+'in the '+category+' category!';
 }


 First Name<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="first_name" maxlength="50" onchange="changingNow"/><br/>
```

Googling this seems to indicate that jQuery is responsible, but there's no jQuery on the page.

EDIT

Rob W is correct, I've already tried brackets, they're irrelevant in sorting this problem.

Comment: Where you have this code and where you call it?

Comment: You mean you see it when you enter stuff (onchange)?

Comment: I checked the error consoles on each browser. Nothing came up, in the actual browser

Comment: try calling the function: `onchange="changingNow()"`

Comment: Is your code inside a `$(document).ready(`?  `changingNow` needs to be global to use it on an inline handler.

Comment: `$(document).ready` is irrelevant. The only thing important is to define function in a global scope. Backslap, try doing `window.changingNow = function() {` instead of `function changingNow() {`

Comment: @freakish: I was asking if was in `$(document).ready(`, because it *shouldn't* be.

Comment: @Rocket Oh, ok. Sorry, I misunderstood you.

Comment: Use var! Poor global namespace! And if you are not using jQuery, why in the world would it be caused by jQuery. Yikes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gentlemen (and ladies??) Our issue seems to have been solved. My issue was, pathetically, that  `<script type="text/javascript">` was omitting the 'text'.

Nevertheless, there are solutions. It seems the () are nessecary, but my thanks to Chris' excellent answer, and indeed his comments about getelementbyid are correct.

Yours etc,

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of problems in your code. For starters, the lines where you get the values of your various text fields is incorrect:

```
first_name=document.getElementById(first_name);
```

`getElementById` expects a string. You aren't passing a string, you're passing an as-yet undefined variable named `first_name`. To make it a string, give some quotes! Second, you aren't using the `var` keyword, which affects the scope of the variable. Lastly, with those two errors corrected, you still aren't getting the value, you're getting the element -- `getElementById` gives you an `HTMLElementObject`. Further on, you try to treat this object as a string:

```
first_name!==""
```

As it stands, first_name will **never** equal an empty string because it is not a string, it is an object. Putting it all together, you want instead:

```
var first_name=document.getElementById('first_name').value;
```

This will give you the value of the text field with the id "first_name" as a string.

Further on, your if statement has way too many parenthesis!

```
if ((first_name!=="")&&(last_name!=="")&&(username!=="")&&(category!="empty"))
```

These parenthesis are not necessary, instead:

```
if (first_name !== "" && last_name !== "" && username !== "" && category!= "empty"){ }

// or my personal preference:

if (
     first_name !== "" &&
     last_name !== "" &&
     username !== "" &&
     category!= "empty"
){ }
```

Finally, I would suggest removing the inline `onchange` event and replacing it with a javascript assignment:

```
document.getElementById('first_name').onchange = changingNow;
```

This is just one way to apply an event, [see this answer for more info on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902033/element-onload-vs-element-addeventlistenerload-callbak-false/6902073#6902073).

Putting it all together:

```
var changingNow = function() {
    var first_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    var last_name = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
    var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
     if (
         first_name !== "" &&
         last_name !== "" &&
         username !== "" &&
         category!= "please choose a category"
    ){
        // this line of code is not valid in regular JS...
        //form1.process.disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('tweet').value = 'I just voted for '+first_name+' '+last_name+' ('+username+')'+' in the '+category+' category!';
    } else {
        // this line of code is not valid in regular JS...
         //form1.process.disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('tweet').value = 'please complete the fields above!';
    }
}
document.getElementById('first_name').onchange = changingNow;
document.getElementById('last_name').onchange = changingNow;
document.getElementById('username').onchange = changingNow;
document.getElementById('category').onchange = changingNow;
changingNow();
```

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/yzbWr/

**Documentation**

- `document.getElementById` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById
- `addEventListener` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element
- Variable scope cheatsheet on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have `function changingNow()` defined AFTER you have inserted the `<input>` field, and because you don't execute it onchange but assign it to onchange (`changingNow()` vs `changingNow`), you end up assigining it an `undefined`

Comment: The *order* of defining is irrelevant as long as the function is defined at the point of changing. The *onchange* defined in HTML is evaluated each time the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this by giving a global namespace to your app and then calling the method explicitly:

```
window.myApp = {};
window.myApp.changingNow = function(){
    // your function code here
};
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" ... onchange="window.myApp.changingNow">
```

Comment: Even better idea is to define handlers only with JavaScript.