# What is the best way to detect an image download completion - onload or addEventListener()?

Tags: javascript

For detecting when an image has completed downloading which method should I use?

```
image.onload = function () {}
```

or

```
image.addEventListener("load", function () {} );
```

Comment: unless I am very much mistaken they are much of a sameness

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902033/element-onload-vs-element-addeventlistenerload-callbak-false - I just found this.

Comment: Study the ins and outs of both, and then decide which to use based on the situation.

Comment: To learn about the differences and much more (!), have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`onload:`

1. Supports only a single listener.
2. Works in all browsers.
3. You unbind the event handler by clearing the `onload` property.

`addEventListener:`

1. Supports multiple listeners.
2. Doesn't work in older IE browsers (they use `attachEvent`).
3. You unbind the listener with `removeEventListener()` which requires info identifying the original eventListener.

If `addEventListener` is supported and you only need one listener, then you can use either.

If it's a simple self-contained piece of code that nobody else will be messing with then, there's no issue with using `onload`.  If it's a more complex piece of software that other developers may mess with and any kind of extensibility is desired and you have cross browser support for event listeners, then `addEventListener()` is more flexible and is probably more desirable.

Comment: Could be worth noting that unbinding is simpler with the `onload` property.

Comment: @thesystem - `removeEventListener` works too and I've never encountered a reason to unbind a load event handler for an image.  In any case, I will add that difference.

Comment: @pure_code - I don't think there's anything wrong with using `onload` in some situations, particular when you want to support older IE browsers and don't already have cross browser event library present (like in a simple stand-alone widget).  Certainly `addEventListener()` is more flexible (supports multiple listeners).

Comment: Passing `{ once: true }` to `addEventListener()` is an alternative for `removeEventListener()` if it'll be done in the first event handler call.

Answer (score 2):

`image.addEventListener("load", function() {} );` will not work on all browsers, but assuming you have a backup and use `image.attachEvent("onload", function() {})`

```
if(image.addEventListener) { image.addEventListener("load",function() {}); }
else { image.attachEvent("onload", function() {}); }
```

This will have the benefit that you are not overriding any onload event that already exists on the image, and that your onload event will not be overridden by any other code.

Directly modifying the "onload" attribute of a DOM Element is usually not recommended just because you may think "Hey, I can save a couple lines of code by setting it, and I only need one listener, so I'll just set it rather than using addEventListener/attachEvent" - but it invariably leads to "Well what if I need to add something else later?"

For this reason javascript developers usually use a library to attach events, so you can add the listener confidently with one line of code and it will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if(image.complete){
  //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both, `Image.complete` as well as `image.onload` don't seem to work in Webkit, at least the version on my mobile. They return `false` infinitely. It works in opera though, so the code may be ok.

Therefore I am currently using a trick that works at least in opera and webkit. I have a 1x1 pixel placeholder image ready. Now I set the `src` to the to be loaded image and (usually a bad practice, but this is a game that cannot start without that image) I go into a loop that updates some "loading" splashscreen gfx, but basicly just checks the width of the image, whether the `image.width` is bigger than 1 pixel.

Like I said, tested only with opera and webkit. I use it to load an atlas image and copy the containing tiles to individual images over a canvas. Once finished, the `src` of the atlas image is set back to the 1x1 placeholder, so it can be used that way again. For complete savity, one should also wait until the placeholder is 1 pixel in width again, before reuseing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleImage=()=>{}
image.addEventListener("load",handleImage);  //adding a eventListener
image.removeEventListener("load",handleImage);  //removeing a eventListener
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.