# Increment a variable in JS from HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I created a small function that causes a number to increase based on clicks. I originally did it all on one file, but I now need to separate it into separate files because I want to use the function as part of my game. Unfortunately, I'm relatively new to Javascript, and I must have messed up somewhere. Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="increaseMainScore()" id="mainPostCard"></button>
    <input type="text" id="outputScore"></input>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var mainScore = 1;

function increaseMainScore() {
    var textBox = document.getElementById("outputScore");
    textBox.value = mainScore;
    mainScore++;
}
```

Also with some CSS test styling and such.

JSfiddle where it works(single page): http://jsfiddle.net/bSt2u/

JSfiddle where it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/AdG8Y/

If anyone could help me solve the issue, that'd be great.

Comment: Use the 'no wrap in <head>' option in your second jsFiddle. You need to check out your console when encountering JS-related issues.

Comment: I don't see a `<script/>` tag in your HTML that points to the .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bSt2u/1/), you have to keep this code either in your page between `script` tags inside `head` like (simplest one)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            var mainScore = 1;
            var btn = document.getElementById('mainPostCard');
            btn.onclick = function(){
                var textBox = document.getElementById("outputScore");
                textBox.value = mainScore;
                mainScore++;    
            };
        };
    </script>
</head>
```

Or keep this code in a separate  `.js` file, i.e (`yourfile.js`) and add it in the `HTML` page using (inside head tags)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902033/element-onload-vs-element-addeventlistenerload-callbak-false).