# Javascript doesn't seems to be running

Tags: javascript

Ok, I have been trying to make it work past 30 minutes.

Everything works fine in this jsfiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/6KT4R/1/

But when I run this on my local wamp server..nothing seems to happen!.

Code :-

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var inputLtc = document.getElementById('input-ltc'),
    inputBtc = document.getElementById('input-btc');

var constantNumber = 0.022632;

inputLtc.onkeyup = function () {
    var result = parseFloat(inputLtc.value) * constantNumber;
    inputBtc.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : '';
};
</script>

<input type="text" name="ltc" id="input-ltc">
<input type="text" name="btc" id="input-btc" readonly>
```

What is possibly wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Why include jQuery if you don't use it?

Comment: Your script is executing before the HTML has been parsed. Move the script below the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is executing before the DOM is loaded.  Try:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var inputLtc = document.getElementById('input-ltc'),
    inputBtc = document.getElementById('input-btc');

    var constantNumber = 0.022632;

    inputLtc.onkeyup = function () {
        var result = parseFloat(inputLtc.value) * constantNumber;
        inputBtc.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : '';
    };
}
```

As m59 suggested there is an improved method of executing the event onload. The following code snippet is preferred:

```
   var funct = function(){
        var inputLtc = document.getElementById('input-ltc'),
        inputBtc = document.getElementById('input-btc');

        var constantNumber = 0.022632;

        inputLtc.onkeyup = function () {
            var result = parseFloat(inputLtc.value) * constantNumber;
            inputBtc.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : '';
        };
    }

    if (window.attachEvent){
       window.attachEvent('onload', funct);
    }else{
       element.addEventListener('load', funct, false);
    }
```

Comment: Or just move the script to the end of the doc.

Comment: It's worth noting that `element.event` such as `window.onload` etc is outdated and it's preferable to use `element.addEventListener`. You have really high rep and I don't mean any offense, but I think it would be good for your answers to recommend best practices. With a rep like yours, your advice carries a lot of weight.

Comment: Good read on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902033/element-onload-vs-element-addeventlistenerload-callbak-false

Comment: m59 Thanks for your suggestions, I have updated the answer.  I don't take offense to your comment, but I will say that it is impossible for everyone to know everything regarding a topic.  I work across a wide array of technologies so keeping up with the latest and greatest is hard.  That is one reason I answer questions on StackOverflow.  I appreciate the downvotes(with explanations) and comments (such as yours) more than the upvotes, since I learn so much more from them.  Thank you for your suggestion, I will utilize this approach in the future.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Nice, man! That's a great attitude. +1 for both :)

Answer (score 2):

You're getting your element references before the elements exist on the page. In the jsfiddle, the javascript is executed after the html. You could reproduce this by moving your script tag below the related html. It is best practice to put all script tags just before the end of the body like this:

```
  <script></script>
</body>
```

Otherwise, you'll need to register an event listener to watch for page load and execute your javascript code then.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('loaded!');
});
```

**with jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('loaded!');
});

//this is the jQuery shorthand for the same function above
$(function() {
  console.log( "loaded!" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks..I'll take care of this from next time.